# Error While Trying To Test App On iPhone

Tags: ios, certificate, device, provisioning

I know this has been asked a hundred times on here, but I've been researching it for hours to no avail, nothing seems to work. I just renewed my membership with Apple and am about to release my first app, but I ran into a small issue while trying to test run my app on my iPhone. I downloaded all the certificates, added them in the keychain, and also created an App ID and a provisioning profile. I'm pretty sure that I added everything in correctly. While trying to run the app, I get an error saying "Code Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier '246CKJ61TR.com.mydomain.myappsname' could not be found".

I added the App ID (246CKJ61TR.com.mydomain.myappsname) into the "Bundle Identifier" in the Info.Plist, but it doesn't seem to do the trick. I also added just "com.mydomain.myappsname" in that field, but neither work.

It seems like there is something small that I am missing here. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use com.mydomain.myappsname for the bundle identifier. Don't prepend the 246CKJ61TR.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! And also, I'm about to submit this app and was wondering if I need to set up a "Distribution Profile" in the bundle before I submit? Thanks again.

Comment: I set up a distribution profile which I use for submitting apps.